# Why am I getting: 'The filename, directory name or volume label syntax incorrect' when passing through parameters in C#

Tags: c#, cmd

My command code is:

```
cmd = @"""" + getLmgrd + @""" -c "+ @""""+ getLic + @""" -z";

Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
info.WorkingDirectory = getDir;
info.Arguments = @"/K " + cmd;
p.StartInfo = info;
p.Start();
```

When I break on  my arguments I get:

```
/K "C:\test\lmgrd.exe" -c "C:\test\z.lic" -z
```

but in CMD I get the error message:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

I'm sure this is an easy answer but it's racking my brains.

EDIT: When I run the argument through CMD (without the /k) it works fine so I know that parameters are fine.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to adjust it so that quotation marks surrounded the whole code:

```
cmd = @"""""" + getLmgrd + @""" -c " +
                    @"""" + getLic + @""" -z""";
```